# What do following asymptotic symbols mean?

Tags: notation, analytic-number-theory

What do these symbols mean? I see them in analytic number theory.

$$\ll$$
$$\gg$$
$$\ll_\epsilon$$
$$\gg_\epsilon$$
$$\asymp$$
$$\sim$$

All these appear in here http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~lenfuchs/Binaryrep.pdf.

Comment: The symbols $\ll$ and $\gg$ are usually not precisely defined, and that shows why it's sometimes important to think about some things before precisely defining things. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Could you please tell me what it means in the paper?

Comment: I'd guess that $x\gg_\epsilon y$ would mean $\frac x\epsilon\gg\frac y\epsilon$.

Comment: Actually, in analytic number theory, the $\ll$ and $\gg$ do have precise senses, essentially as in @Jeb's answer below. Admittedly, in other contexts, they do not. How to know? That's the real problem.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The third and fourth symbols $\ll_\epsilon$ and $\gg_\epsilon$ mean that one number is greater/smaller than the other by a constant $\epsilon$. Since it is $\ll$ and $\gg$ as opposed to $<$ and $>$, then $\epsilon \ll 1$ always (as opposed to $\epsilon < 1$); for example, $x \gg_\epsilon y \Leftrightarrow x \gg y + \epsilon$ such that $\epsilon \ll 1$ and $x >_\epsilon y \Leftrightarrow x > y + \epsilon$ such that $\epsilon < 1$. See what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all completely standard notations, and are used often in analytic number theory. (I've used them all at some point or another.) I would say that mathematicians working in analytic number theory would all be pretty comfortable with these notations and would not expect them to be defined in a paper. In a textbook, on the other hand, they'd probably be written down somewhere: for example, I believe there is a list of such definitions at the beginning of Montgomery and Vaughan's book.

We say that $f(x) \ll g(x)$ (implicitly understood as $x \to \infty$) if $f(x) = O(g(x))$, or equivalently if
\[\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} = C < \infty\]
for some nonnegative constant $C$. Note that $g(x)$ is usually implicitly assumed to be a positive function, at least for all $x$ sufficiently large.

Similarly, $f(x) \gg g(x)$ (again implicitly understood as $x \to \infty$) if $g(x) = O(f(x))$, or equivalently if
\[\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = C < \infty\]
for some nonnegative constant $C$. Here both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are implicitly understood to be positive functions.

The notation $\ll_{\varepsilon}$ implies that the implicit constant $C$ depends on the parameter $\varepsilon$. For example, if we let $f(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n)$, the Mertens function, and $g(x) = x^{1/2 + \varepsilon}$, which depends on the parameter $\varepsilon$, then the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the statement $f(x) \ll_{\varepsilon} g(x)$. This is also written as $f(x) = O_{\varepsilon}(g(x))$. This means that
\[\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} = C < \infty\]
for some nonnegative constant $C = C(\varepsilon)$ *that is allowed to depend on the parameter $\varepsilon$*.

The notation $\gg_{\varepsilon}$ is defined analogously.

The notation $f(x) \asymp g(x)$ means that both $f(x) \gg g(x)$ and $f(x) \ll g(x)$ hold simultaneously. For an example, take $f(x) = x + \sin x$ and $g(x) = x$.

The notation $f(x) \sim g(x)$ is occasionally also written as $f(x) = (1 + o(1)) g(x)$ or $f(x) = g(x) + o(g(x))$. It simply means that $f(x) - g(x) = o(g(x))$, or equivalently that
\[\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x) - g(x)|}{g(x)} = 0.\]

The one other common definition that you don't mention is $\Omega$. We write $f(x) = \Omega(g(x))$ if
\[\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)}> 0.\]
It may be the case that this limit is $\infty$, and this is certainly allowed. For example, take $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$. One can be more precise and write $f(x) = \Omega_+(g(x))$ if
\[\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0,\]
and similarly $f(x) = \Omega_-(g(x))$ if
\[\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 0.\]

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be the following:
$$ f \ll g \iff f \in \mathcal{O}(g) \iff \limsup_{X \to \infty} \left | \frac{ f}{g} \right | < \infty$$
The next I'm not sure, but I'd guess he means
$$ f \ll_{\epsilon} g(\epsilon) \iff \limsup_{X \to \infty} \left | \frac{ f}{g} \right | = M(\epsilon) < \infty $$
Then 
$$ f \asymp  g \iff f \ll g\quad  \&  \quad g \ll f$$ 
Lastly
$$ f \sim g \iff  \lim_{X \to \infty} \frac{f}{g} = 1 $$

Comment: Yes, except I think $f\sim g$ means that the limit exists, and is $1$.

Comment: What is $M(\epsilon)$?

Comment: A function that depends on $\epsilon$, i.e. the symbol controls the growth only for certain values of $\epsilon$.

Comment: @paulgarrett, I think you're right on second though.

Answer (score 0):

The authors should have explained their notation, so shame on Bourgain and Fuchs.  I've never seen something like $\leq_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: It's not meant to be $\le_\varepsilon$, but $\ll_\varepsilon$, in TeX "\\ll". In some circles this notation is constantly used... although I agree that it'd not be hard to explain it. I think it took me many years to catch on that it had a precise meaning, rather than some sort of vague hand-wavey sense.