# What does the symbol $\gtrsim$ mean?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

What does the symbol $\gtrsim$ mean exactly?
I know $f(x) \sim g(x)$  ($x \to x_0)$ means $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1 $.

does $\gtrsim$ mean  $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\geq 1 ? $
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the code `\to` yields the symbol $\to$; it's an alias for `\rightarrow` ($\rightarrow$).

Comment: @PatrickStevens thanks

Comment: This is not standard notation in analytic number theory. It may be more common in harmonic analysis (where $\lesssim$ is certainly commonly used). But I would imagine it means the same thing as $\gg$, which I defined in an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416044/what-do-following-asymptotic-symbols-mean/1416241#1416241

Answer (score 1):

The use I make in analysis is:

$$f\gtrsim g\iff  \exists + \infty>C>0 \text{ s.t } f\geq C\cdot g$$

Comment: Thanks! do you have any links on it for me?

Comment: Actually... no, I actually cannot find any good link at the moment. If I find one, I'll post it.

Comment: @b00nheT: what does "s.t." stand for? (such that?) thanks!

Comment: @mike yes: *such that*

Answer (score 1):

I have a different answer from that of b00n heT's.  That interpretation is something I have seen in harmonic analysis but it is not the convention in analytic number theory (which would use the notation $f \gg g$ to describe the same situation).

When I write $f \gtrsim g$, it means that $f$ is greater than $g$ up to an asymptotically small error.  That is, there exists a function $h(x)$ such that $f(x) \ge g(x) - h(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)/g(x) = 0$.

Note that this definition is still sensible even if $g$ is negative (in contrast to the definition proposed in the OP), and it doesn’t require the limit $f/g$ to exist.  It also means the constant matters, so you couldn't say that $x \gtrsim 2x$.

Comment: That is not what $\gg$ is used to mean in analytic number theory.

Comment: @Erick Wong . do you have any links for me?

Comment: @PeterHumphries Care to provide more details?  If you're talking about subtle points of distinction (particularly with regard to negative values), then I agree they are not necessarily identical.  But in spirit, $\gg$ in analytic number theory captures the same $g = O(f)$ idea as the answer given by b00n heT.  Your blanket negation, however, is not very helpful.

Comment: Oh sorry! You've written $f(x) \geq g(x) - h(x)$ when I think you should mean $f(x) \geq C g(x) - h(x)$ for some constant $C > 0$. If that's what you meant, then it does mean the same as $\gg$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I think you misunderstand.  I'm saying that $\gg$ and $\gtrsim$ don't mean the same thing (which would be a bit redundant), but that $\gg$ as used in analytic number theory means about the same as $\gtrsim$ in harmonic analysis.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I misinterpreted your first two sentences. You're right.